# How to add a default sound in MS PowerPoint to a shape in a slide using c#

Tags: c#

Here is my code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape rectangle = curSlide.Shapes.AddShape(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeRoundedRectangle, slideWidth - 110, slideHeight - 60, 100, 50);
Sequence objSequence = curSlide.TimeLine.InteractiveSequences.Add(1);
Effect pEffect_start = objSequence.AddEffect(rectangle, MsoAnimEffect.msoAnimEffectTransparency, MsoAnimateByLevel.msoAnimateLevelNone, MsoAnimTriggerType.msoAnimTriggerOnShapeClick, 1);
```

I can add an animation to shape, but with a sound I can not.

I do not want to add file in a location:

```
rectangle.AnimationSettings.SoundEffect.ImportFromFile(fileLocation);
```

I want to add default sounds in Powerpoint:

[image: Powerpoint object sounds picket]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

let you try to add this line of code after yours

```
pEffect_start.EffectInformation.PlaySettings.PlayOnEntry = Office.MsoTriState.msoCTrue;
```

The PlayOnEntry means the media is played/ not played on load event. This property is supported even before MS Powerpoint 2007

Comment: Vâng, nhưng nó không chạy ạ, cháu muốn add cái âm thanh vào shape đã được tạo ra trên point mà khó quá. Toàn lỗi thôi ạ.