# How to add a sound to a shape in a slide MS powerpoint using c#

Tags: c#

Here is my code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape rectangle = curSlide.Shapes.AddShape(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeRoundedRectangle, slideWidth - 110, slideHeight - 60, 100, 50);
Sequence objSequence = curSlide.TimeLine.InteractiveSequences.Add(1);
Effect pEffect_start = objSequence.AddEffect(rectangle, MsoAnimEffect.msoAnimEffectTransparency, MsoAnimateByLevel.msoAnimateLevelNone, MsoAnimTriggerType.msoAnimTriggerOnShapeClick, 1);
```

I can add an animation to shape, but with a sound I can not.
How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to play the sound of a shape in PowerPoint using c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43098910/how-to-play-the-sound-of-a-shape-in-powerpoint-using-c-sharp)

Comment: Please don't post the same question multiple times.

Comment: No, #Stijn, in this question, I just want to add sound in shape, not the default sound in MS Powerpoint.